# Should samsung-gt-i5800 be merged to samsung-galaxy-3?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Just as the title says, same model, different names.

EDIT: my bad, meant samsung-gt-i5800, not samsung-galaxy-i5800 which has been a synonym as Matthew Read commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, make more sense now.  Done!

Answer (score 1):

Good idea, I see no reason why not.